# What does it mean to show sympathy for the other ticket

Tags: phrases, idioms

In the movie "All The President's Men", the vice president says that at the airport. What does it mean? What is "the other ticket" referring to?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right movie or quote?  http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/All-the-President%27s-Men.html  I can't find any reference to your question in the script.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because I'm reading from the subtitle that has been so accurate till this point in the movie. Based on the Wikipedia quote "In 1968, Muskie was nominated for Vice President on the Democratic ticket", I think it means that with this phrase, the vice president is accusing the Washington Post reporters and editors to be a Republican or one who is from the other party or a fan of that party. Am I right?

Comment: By the way, the mentioned script is not complete. For example, when Woodward comes to the court and talks to Caddy, he first asks his surname, but it's not written in the script

Comment: @JoeDark That script is subtitled "Pre-rehearsal version March, 1975" - according to Wikipedia, "Principal photography began on May 12, 1975 in Washington, D.C."

Comment: Again, moderators close a question (maybe just for being an active moderator)! How do you say this question "can be answered using commonly-available references". I didn't find any meaning for this in any dictionary or a reference site, that's why I asked here. If the meaning was in any online source, I wouldn't bother to ask (and wait some time for the answer). I don't count a not-so-straightforward technical article as a source for an English phrase definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *other ticket* refers to the candidates of the other party who are on the ballot.

A party presents a given set of candidates for election to a given set of offices. That set of candidates is the *ticket* of that party. The *other ticket* is a ticket for another party. When there are essentially only two (main) parties, it is clear what the *other* ticket is, relative to either ticket.

Presumably, the Vice President was speaking of someone in his own party who showed some sympathy for the other party, or at least the other party's offering in the given election - its *ticket*.

In addition, in US elections, a party presents a candidate for President and Vice President, and they run together, as a single [*ticket*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_(election)) (Wikipedia).

Comment: An explanation so perfect it could not be polished.